# why is my list variable changing when I am not making it?

Tags: python

this seems like such a simple thing but i can't understand why this is happening.

```
x = list(input('>>> '))
y = x

for i in range(len(y)):
  if y[i].isalpha():
    y[i] = '_'
print(x,y)
```

for some reason the x list is changing from the user input into underscores when I only made the y variable change. I don't how this is working and I would apreciate if someone could explain this. sorry if i am just super stupid and and cannot see some clear thing lol. thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not copying the list. You have two references to the same list.

Comment: y = x.copy() otherwise you create a reference, like a synonym.

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html